# Craft CMS admin intermittent internal server errors

Tags: craft3, database, error

I'm getting intermittent Internal server errors in Craft admin.

This has happened out of the blue on an active site. Craft pro 3.041

phperrors.log:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: constraint_name in /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php on line 387
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: referenced_table_name in /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php on line 387
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: constraint_name in /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php on line 388
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: column_name in /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php on line 388
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: referenced_column_name in /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php on line 388
```

stack trace:

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Undefined index: constraint_name in /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php:387
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(76): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/libraries...', 387)
#1 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(387): craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/libraries...', 387, Array)
#2 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/mysql/Schema.php(260): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findConstraints(Object(craft\db\TableSchema))
#3 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/mysql/Schema.php(244): craft\db\mysql\Schema->findConstraints(Object(craft\db\TableSchema))
#4 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(744): craft\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema('categorygroups')
#5 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(194): yii\db\Schema->getTableMetadata('{{%categorygrou...', 'schema', false)
#6 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(384): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%categorygrou...')
#7 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(458): yii\db\ActiveRecord::getTableSchema()
#8 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQueryTrait.php(123): yii\db\ActiveRecord::populateRecord(Object(craft\records\CategoryGroup), Array)
#9 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php(207): yii\db\ActiveQuery->createModels(Array)
#10 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(238): yii\db\ActiveQuery->populate(Array)
#11 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php(133): yii\db\Query->all(NULL)
#12 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Categories.php(147): yii\db\ActiveQuery->all()
#13 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Categories.php(168): craft\services\Categories->getAllGroups()
#14 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(304): craft\services\Categories->getEditableGroups()
#15 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(240): craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset->_editableCategoryGroups()
#16 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php(91): craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset->_craftData()
#17 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(266): craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset->registerAssetFiles(Object(craft\web\View))
#18 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(1476): yii\web\View->registerAssetFiles('craft\\web\\asset...')
#19 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(264): craft\web\View->registerAssetFiles('craft\\web\\asset...')
#20 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(1476): yii\web\View->registerAssetFiles('spicyweb\\embedd...')
#21 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(162): craft\web\View->registerAssetFiles('spicyweb\\embedd...')
#22 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(870): yii\web\View->endBody()
#23 /home/sitename/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/09/099ec019af86e34b9ea9f63b2dbac8d74176f8466496d8a2425bb84f3bec877f.php(66): craft\web\View->endBody()
#24 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_9aa2dcb82b219a2fa85db09c73326448a71cbe86b0372bc433523ac598499391->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#25 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#26 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#27 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#28 /home/sitename/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/09/091b800fabb88c3d6e62016f577589ccd5e7c12aa48a1467f1257ce83d37d043.php(40): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#29 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_0e919918d332266787684ee1ea6d42db967f13e4cb8da3aeadda81eec7091361->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#30 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#31 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#32 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#33 /home/sitename/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/e9/e93cb237d31ded69afdaf6d6597608b057cf095c8b34c5fa7bdbe9d90ed6bd25.php(55): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#34 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_5707e1b3f57ed73779ccae5f2a7fa1e6916724c0d2e401b30a13dba031a03c95->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#35 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#36 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#37 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#38 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(371): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array)
#39 /home/sitename/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(289): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#40 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(331): Twig_Environment->render('login', Array)
#41 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(378): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('login', Array)
#42 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(156): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('login', Array)
#43 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php(78): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('login', Array)
#44 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('login', Array)
#45 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#46 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#47 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(104): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#48 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#49 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(284): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#50 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#51 /home/sitename/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(273): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#52 /home/sitename/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#53 /home/sitename/public_html/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#54 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an old bug that was fixed in a more recent version of Craft than the one you are on - https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6379

Are you able to update Craft and your plugins to the latest version?